# URL Routing is not working in asp.net4 when published

Tags: url-routing

I used      ` RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute for my pages in website 
same as 
                        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute(1,
                       "~/LNG/WebSites/Vission/vissions.aspx","vission");

RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute(2,
                       "~/LNG/WebSites/Loss/LossCiculars.aspx","Loss Circular");
 `....

but this worked for some page .
i have an error for other page http 404

in web.config i added this line 
  `<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />    </modules>
  </system.webServer>`

Note : this code worked correctly when i have run project in v.s.
help me plz if you can 
thanks